# open covering of $S^1\times S^1$

Tags: covering-spaces

Show that the map $\psi_{m,n}:S^1×S^1→S^1×S^1$given by $(z,w)→(z^m,w^n)$ where $mn≠0$ is a covering map.

My attempt is $\psi_n:S^1\to S^1$ given by $z\to z^n$ is a covering map for $n\neq0$.Similarly $\psi_m:S^1\to S^1$ given by $z\to z^m$ is a covering map.Now,use the theorem we get $\psi_n\times\psi_m:S^1×S^1→S^1×S^1$ that is $\psi_{m,n}$ is covering map.Is my attempt correct?

Comment: can you do this for $S^1$?

Comment: no can not do this for $S^1$.If I can do for $S^1$ then their product follows for $S^1\times S^1$

Comment: It's helpful to describe points in the circle as exp(ix), so squaring doubles the angle. Try for m =2 first.

Comment: you say that $e^{i\theta}\to e^2{i\theta}$ but what will be the disjoints sets then?

Comment: if we take $U=\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in(0,2\pi)\}$ then$V_k=\{e^{i\theta}:\theta\in\(2\pi k/n,2\pi k/n+\pi/n)\}$.I think this forms disjoint union. Is it true?